# How to interpret this part of device tree?

Tags: device-tree

The following snippet in the .dts is describing the reserved memory:

```
reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <0x2>;
    #size-cells = <0x2>;
    ranges;

    cma_reserved: linux,cma {
        compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
        reusable;
        size = <0x0 0x1000000>; // 16MB
        alignment = <0x0 0x2000>; // 8KB
        linux,cma-default;
    };

    ion_reserved: ion@200000000 {
        compatible = "ion-region";
        reg = <0x2 0x0 0x1 0x0>; // 4GB
    };
};
```

I can understand the `ion_reserved` part, but don't understand the `cma_reserved` part, particulary about the address of this 16MB of memory.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `compatible` property string to identify the driver that depends on this node.

Answer (score 1):

**CMA** (Contiguous Memory allocation): This allocation is used because dma require Contiguous memory and with  available allocater we can only allocate 8 MB at max. so we use cma(reserve memory) at boot time.

**Properties used in Above node:**

- Compatible property will specify which driver can use this node.
  Drivers mentioning  **.compatible="shared-dma-pool"** in their device
  id table, Can use this node for driver.
- Reusable property- It is a optional and as well as empty property.
  When a node specify this property means, OS can use this memory in
  this region but their is a limitation that device driver when require
  this contentious memory they can reclaim it back.
- Size property- This property tells you the total size of cma and as
  it is 16 MB in the above node.
- Alignment property- Address boundary for alignment of allocation. It
  also use size cell of 2 as specified by the parent. That's why it is
  "alignment = <0x0 0x2000>;"
- linux,cma-default property- It is also a empty property. If this
  property is mentioned then Linux will use this memory region for
  default for contiguous memory allocation. Their is also a similar
  property "linux,dma-default" if this property is mentioned then Linux
  will use this pool region for DMA allocator. In case of cma first
  property is used and dma use second property.

For More info visit: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt

Comment: Thanks for you answer. From the link you provided, I see the following ` Each child node may either use a 'reg' property to
specify a specific range of reserved memory, or a 'size' property with
optional constraints to request a dynamically allocated block of memory.` So basically the address of this block of memory is dynamically allocated, this is what I was asking for help. So if I understand it correctly, this block of memory will be allocated from the `memory` node by the kernel and passed to the driver...

Comment: ps: the boot log from kernel confirms that the 16MiB cma memory is allocated from the system memory (at the top of it).

Comment: I cannot understand question what are u are asking of?? @bruin

Comment: My question is particulary about the base address of the 16MB cma memory, since the device tree only specifies the size of the block, not its base address. And now I think I have the answer: the memory is allocated by kernel from the system memory (the `memory` node which is not listed in my question),  thus the base address is kind of determined by kernel. The console log shows that this cma block sits at the top of the physical system memory.

Answer (score 0):

The doc (as indicated by Jitender) plus the console log from kernel suggest that the `cma` block is allocated from system memory.

The `memory` node in device tree:

```
memory {
  reg = <0x1 0x0 0x0 0xB0000000>; // 2.75GB, lease last 1.25GB to video codec
  device_type = "memory";
};
```

Kernel log for `cma` block:

```
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000001af000000, size 16 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
```

And I guess the following reflects the physical memory map confirming to that part of the device tree:

```
+=========================+ 0x3:0000:0000
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|        ION (4G)         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+=========================+  0x2:0000:0000
|                         |
|   Video decode (1.25G)  |
|                         |
+-------------------------+  0x1:b000:0000
|     CMA pool (16M)      |
|  ---------------------  |  0x1:af00:0000
|   crash kernel (64M)    |
|  ---------------------  |  0x1:ab00:0000
|                         |
|                         |
|     System (2.75G)      |
|                         |
+=========================+  0x1:0000:0000
```

Thanks!